For a functional, why is a subspace $J$ ideal?
I'm reading "A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory" (you can read here) and I'm trying to show a subset $J$ is an ideal(p140-p141). Following images include notations.
Here, upper line is complex conjugation, $D$ is a positive integer,
$\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{DN})$ is Schwartz space on $\mathbb{R}^{DN}$ and $J =\{f\in \underline{\mathscr{S}}:\mu(\underline{f}\times \underline{f})=0 \}$.
Suppose $\underline{f}\in J$ and $g\in \underline{\mathscr{S}}$. I tried to calculate
\begin{align}
 \mu((\overline{\underline{g}\times \underline{f}}) \times (\underline{g}\times \underline{f}))&=\sum_{N=1}\mu_{N}((\sum_{l=0}^{j} \overline{g_{l}}\overline{f_{j-l}})(\sum_{k=0}^{N-j}g_{k}f_{N-j-k}))
\end{align}
However, I could not factorize it by $\mu (\overline{\underline{f}}\times \underline{f})$.
Any hint also helps me. Thanks for reading.

This is similar to an argument used in the context of positive linear functionals on $C^*$-algebras so I had something in mind already.
$\omega$ defines a positive semidefinite sesquilinear form (also called a semi-inner product) and thus satisfies the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$|\omega(\underline{u},\underline{v})|^2 \leq \omega(\underline{u},\underline{u}) \omega(\underline{v},\underline{v})$$
Therefore, for $\underline{v} = \underline{f}$ you get:
$$\forall \underline{u},\quad \omega(\underline{u}, \underline{f}) = \mu(\overline{\underline{u}} \times \underline{f}) = 0$$
Taking $\underline{u} = \overline{\left(\overline{(\underline{g} \times \underline{f})} \times \underline{g}\right)}$ reveals that:
$$\mu(\overline{(\underline{g} \times \underline{f})} \times (\underline{g} \times \underline{f})) = \mu(\overline{\underline{u}} \times \underline{f}) =  0$$
and $J$ is a left ideal.
Similarly, first taking $\underline{u} = \underline{f}$ and then $\underline{v} = \overline{\underline{g}} \times (\underline{f} \times \underline{g})$ yields:
$$\mu(\overline{(\underline{f} \times \underline{g})} \times (\underline{f} \times \underline{g})) = \mu(\overline{\underline{f}} \times \underline{v}) = 0$$
so that $J$ is indeed a two-sided ideal.

Thanks!!! It's really kind and clear to understand!
